# Show div on cart page based on backorder status and time of day

Tags: php, if-statement, woocommerce

I've written a statement which allows me to echo a DIV on the checkout page based on if the order has backorder products (this works) but i want it to based on the time of the day as well.

Here's my code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'redpakket_items_checkout_notice' );
function redpakket_items_checkout_notice() {
    $found = false;

    foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if( $cart_item['data']->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam");
    if( in_array(date("H"), array("22", "23")) && in_array(date("N"), array("1", "2", "3", "4")) ||  $found) {
        echo '<div>Test</div>';
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should print the output? of your variables, to see if they have been met

By using `||` only 1 of the conditions has to be met

```php
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Amsterdam");

$hour = date("H");
$day_of_the_week = date("N");

echo 'f = ' . $found . '<br>';
echo 'h = ' . $hour . '<br>';
echo 'd = ' . $day_of_the_week . '<br>';

if( in_array($hour, array("12", "23")) && in_array($day_of_the_week, array("1", "2", "3", "4")) && $found ) {
    echo '<div>Test</div>';
} else {
    echo 'not';
}
```

Comment: Hi, this eventually worked for me, although there was no need for me to echo the different strings. Thanks allot.